# Accessing the array values for array returned by OData service VS creating in program - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have an array whose values are accessed in following manner:
The first one is when the cart has items returned from the oData and the second one is when I am creating the array for a new product to be added to the cart.
The VSet.results in one case of products (already saved) and VSet[0] for new products is causing issues for me while trying to loop over this array and specifically find the values of the VSet. Because if I just mention VSet[0] it causes error for the already saved items. How to make these both work using same syntax line?

this.getView().getModel("A").oData.AData[0].VSet.results[0]

this.getView().getModel("A").oData.AData[4].VSet[0]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new OData record you should use the [createEntry](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createEntry) method of your ODataModel. This method will create a temporary entity that you will need to submit to the backend server via the [submitChanges](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/submitChanges) method.

If you want to directly create an OData record on your backend system you can use the [create](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/create) method.